# Why is $|\mathbb N | = |\mathbb Z|$?

Tags: infinity, infinite-groups

I am starting a new class of theory of computation (you know, where we talk about the turing machine, etc etc) and I am having some difficulties to understand that $|\mathbb N| = |\mathbb Z|$ (they are the same infinite). Before I started this class my intuition always said that $|\mathbb N| < |\mathbb Z|$. Can some one here with your own words explain to me why are $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$ the same infinite?

Thanks!

Comment: Because you can set up a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: See the answers here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227280/are-there-an-equal-number-of-positive-and-negative-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smallest cardinality is called *countable* or *listable*. These are the sets which you can write out as a list. For example

$$\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots \}$$

and

$$\mathbb{Z} = \{\ldots, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$$

are both lists. One of them happens to be bidirectional.

It turns out that if you can list a set with a bidirectional list, then you can list it with a monodirectional list. The way to do this is essentially to fold the list in half and zipper the two halves together. That is,

$$ \mathbb{Z} = \{ 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, \ldots \}. $$

If you can write a a set $S$ as a monodirectional list $S = \{s_0, s_1, s_2, \dots\}$ in this way, you get a bijection between that set and the natural numbers by sending $s_n$ to $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But one thing I can´t understand is... As you can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument Cantor said that infinite sequences of binary numbers are uncountable but at the same time I can think of a binary number as a decimal number and create a  bijection f: N -> BinaryNumbers. Am I thinking in a wrong way here? Because I does not make sense...

Comment: @Daniel You can think of a *finite* binary sequence as a decimal number but not an *infinite* one.